# Bootstrap 4 table with table-fixed class won't set background-color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-color, bootstrap-table

I've seen some similar questions from long ago, but can't find anything up to date that fits the current situation.

I have a table which uses the "table-fixed" and "table-striped" classes, but does not display the background color for the alternate rows.

- If I remove the "table-fixed" class, the striping works as designed.
- If I inspect a table row using DevTools, I can see that the background-color IS set correctly. But it does NOT display correctly.

Here's the pertinent chunks of code:

**Jobs.cshtml**

```
<table id="jobtable" class="table table-sm  table-fixed  table-striped table-condensed ">
        <thead style="background-color: lightgray">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="col-1" style="text-align:center">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.AllSelected, new { value = Model.AllSelected, id = "ckboxall" })</th>
                <th scope="col" class="col-1" style="text-align:center">#</th>
                <th scope="col" class="col-4" style="text-align:left">Format</th>
                <th scope="col" class="col-1" style="text-align:left">Qty</th>
                <th scope="col" class="col-5" style="text-align:left">Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
            {
            <tr>
                <td class="col-1" style="text-align:center">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.AllSelected, new { value = Model.AllSelected, @class = "ckbox" })</td>
                <td class="col-1" style="text-align:center">@i</td>
                <td class="col-4" style="text-align:left">Test</td>
                <td class="col-1" style="text-align:left">Test</td>
                <td class="col-5" style="text-align:left">Test</td>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

**site.css**

```
    .table-fixed tbody {
        height: 300px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .table-fixed thead,
    .table-fixed tbody,
    .table-fixed tr,
    .table-fixed td,
    .table-fixed th {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed tbody th, .table-fixed thead > tr > th {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .table-fixed tbody td::after, .table-fixed tbody th::after, .table-fixed thead > tr > th::after {
        content: '';
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
    /*
    *
    * Custom Table Striping
    *
    */
    .table-striped#jobtable tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #cef5d8 !important;
    }
    
    th, td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change Custom Table Striping Code

```
 #jobtable.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
            background-color: #cef5d8 !important;
        }

            th, td {
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
            }
```

To This

```
#jobtable.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd)>td{
            background-color: #cef5d8 !important;
        }

            th, td {
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
            }
```